# View not dismissing after UIAlertAction taken

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

So I am using a UIAlertController with an Action Sheet style to display two options, one to cancel the action and another to delete the data. The buttons work fine and the delete button works and the Action Sheet dismisses. My problem is that the view itself does not dismiss after the data is deleted from the cloud in the background. Why isn't the view dismissing itself?

```
@IBAction func deleteRecipePressed() {
// Create the alert controller
let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Delete Recipe?", message: "Are you positive you want to delete this recipe? This action can not be undone!", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

// Create and add the cancel action
let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: {action -> Void in
  // Just dismiss the action sheet
})
actionSheetController.addAction(cancelAction)

// Create and add the delete action
let deleteAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .Default, handler: {action -> Void in
  // Set deleteRecipe to true to flag for deletion
  self.deleteRecipe = true
})
actionSheetController.addAction(deleteAction)

// Present the alert
self.presentViewController(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)

// If flagged for deletion, delete the recipe and dismiss the view
if (deleteRecipe == true) {
  recipeObject.deleteInBackground()
  self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Comment: I think you should use the UIAlertController dismissViewControllerAnimated function to dismiss when your data is delete by you. Or you post a custom notification to handle this case.

Comment: It's worth noting that a **REALLY SLOPPY 'QUICK FIX'** for this problem is: simply **turn off the animation**.  i.e., animated == false.  This, generally, prevents the racetrack condition in question; also you conveniently then do not have to bother learning how to program it the hard way!  (I love that :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code -

```
// If flagged for deletion, delete the recipe and dismiss the view
if (deleteRecipe == true) {
  recipeObject.deleteInBackground()
  self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Executes immediately after the action sheet is shown. i.e. before the user has selected either option.  `self.presentViewController(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)` does not block the current thread.

You need to delete your item and dismiss your view in the handler for the `delete` option -

```
let deleteAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .Default, handler: {action -> Void in
  recipeObject.deleteInBackground()
  self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
})
```

Comment: This worked. I tried this earlier and I was getting some weird error in the Parse framework telling me BFTask was not convertible to (). Tried this again and it worked this time! Thanks! Also quick question, in that same handler, would it be possible to tell the super views tableView to reload the data to reflect the deletion?

Comment: You could post a notification, but normally you would do this via unwind segue or in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I think the viewWillAppear should work well. Thanks again for the help!